# JPA and spring handling of DAO with exceptions and generics

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, generics, jpa

`javax.transaction.TransactionRequiredException`' is never thrown in the corresponding try block

ref: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#merge%28T%29

note: I dont want to declare `throws new exception` in my method signature

how to `handle exceptions`?

and I was thinking that `.save .merge` are used in all `DAOs`. So writing same code foe each DAO with just different object (but same pattern) would not be smart `OOP.`

How to *properly* make `generic .merge .save` or thus all such repeated things.

I couldnt find much stable examples on google though.

any sample code ?

```
private EntityManager entityManager;

    public Boards save(Boards board) {
          Boards boardToBeReturned = null;
          try{
              boardToBeReturned = entityManager.merge(board);
          }catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
              e.printStackTrace();
          }catch (TransactionRequiredException e){
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

          return boardToBeReturned;
    }
```

complete sample code for a class:

```
package web.dao.impl.jpa;

import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContextType;
import javax.transaction.TransactionRequiredException;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import web.dao.BoardsDAO;
import web.entity.Boards;
import web.entity.Users;


@Repository
public class BoardsDAOImpl implements BoardsDAO {

    /**
     * The JPA entity manager
     */
//  @Autowired
    @PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public Boards save(Boards board) {
        Boards boardToBeReturned = null;
        try{
            boardToBeReturned = entityManager.merge(board);
        }catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
             e.printStackTrace();
//        }catch (TransactionRequiredException e){
//            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return boardToBeReturned;
    }


    public Boards getBoardById(Long id){
        Boards boardToBeReturned = null;
        System.out.println("board id entered for lookup was : "+id);
        try {
            boardToBeReturned=entityManager.find(Boards.class, id);
        }catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
               e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return boardToBeReturned;
    }


    @PersistenceContext
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    /**
     * Helper method to return the hibernate session from the JPA
     * entity manager implementation.
     * 
     * @return the hibernate {#link Session}
     */
    protected Session getHibernateSession() {
        return entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
    }


        public List<Boards> getBoardListByUser(Users user){

            return null;
        }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IllegalArgumentException and TransactionRequiredException are runtime exceptions, indicating a programming bug. You shouldn't catch them. And if you catch them, the worse thing to do is to ignore them like you're doing and pretend like nothing happened. Your method should simply look like this:

```
public Boards save(Boards board) {
    return entityManager.merge(board);
}
```

Since you're using Spring and looking for generic DAOs, then look at the [Spring Data JPA](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/) project, which provides just that, and more.

Comment: nice. why not catch the exceptions in catch block? and can you elaborate the runtime exception thing and programming bug

Comment: These exceptions are there to signal the developer that he didn't respect the rules. By catching them, you don't signal it to the developer anymore, and let him continue to use the entity manager as if nothing bad happened, although these exceptions leave the entity manager in an inconsistent state, with the transaction marked for rollback. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example interface:

```
public interface GenericDao<T, PK extends Serializable> {
    T create(T t);
    T read(PK id);
    T update(T t);
    void delete(T t);
}
```

And an implementation:

```
public class GenericDaoJpaImpl<T, PK extends Serializable> 
    implements GenericDao<T, PK> {

    protected Class<T> entityClass;

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    public GenericDaoJpaImpl() {
        ParameterizedType genericSuperclass = (ParameterizedType) getClass()
             .getGenericSuperclass();
        this.entityClass = (Class<T>) genericSuperclass
             .getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    @Override
    public T create(T t) {
        this.entityManager.persist(t);
        return t;
    }

    @Override
    public T read(PK id) {
        return this.entityManager.find(entityClass, id);
    }

    @Override
    public T update(T t) {
        return this.entityManager.merge(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(T t) {
        t = this.entityManager.merge(t);
        this.entityManager.remove(t);
    }
}
```

Log the Exceptions and re-throw them as `RuntimeException` for the caller.

**Logging the exceptions:-** Print/Log stack trace in catch block, so that if caller of the method forget it to log you have already done it in your `GenergicDAO`

**Re-Throwing the exception :-** So that caller can catch that exception and rollback etc whatever he want to do

Comment: nice, can you elaborate "log the exceptions and rethrow them as runtime exception" any why?